# Trying to send multiple e-mails with PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to send e-mails to all customers with an invitation to complete a form. The email contains login information to the website, and thus it is a different mail for each customer. I have over 600 customers in total, but i am trying to send in groups of 100. However, it only sends to the first 24-25 recipients.
I am very new at this, could you please help me out?

Here is my code:

1. Form that picks all email addresses for the first 100 customers, and should send a custom message to each when i click send:

   ```
   <?php
   include ('header.php');
   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "export_declarations");
   $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT c_id, company_name,username,password,name, email,   authorized_person_name,authorized_person_email FROM test_invite
       WHERE c_id<75 AND (grouping ='' OR grouping LIKE '%no agreement%' OR grouping LIKE '%merger with client%')");
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
      {
           $data[$row['c_id']]['ID'] = $row['c_id'];
           $data[$row['c_id']]['comp_name'] = $row['company_name'];
           $data[$row['c_id']]['contacts'] = $row['name'];
           $data[$row['c_id']]['contacts_emails'] = str_replace(",",", ",$row['email']);
           $data[$row['c_id']]['authorized_contact_name'] = $row['authorized_person_name'];
           $data[$row['c_id']]['authorized_contact_email'] = $row['authorized_person_email'];
           $data[$row['c_id']]['username'] = $row['username'];
           $data[$row['c_id']]['password'] = $row['password'];
       }

   $html = "<table>
           <form method = 'post'>
               <th><u>A.</u> <br/>Company ID</th>
               <th><u>B.</u> <br/> Company name</th>
               <th><u>C.</u> <br/> All contacts</th>
               <th><u>D.</u> <br/> E-mails, all contacts</th>
               <th><u>E.</u> <br/> Authorized contact</th>
               <th><u>F.</u> <br/> E-mail, authorized contact</th>";

   foreach ($data as $key=>$val)
   {
           $html .= "<tr>
                   <input type = 'hidden' name = 'name[{$key}]' value = '{$data[$key]['authorized_contact_name']}'>
                   <input type = 'hidden' name = 'email[{$key}]' value = '{$data[$key]['authorized_contact_email']}'>
                   <input type = 'hidden' name = 'username[{$key}]' value = '{$data[$key]['username']}'>
                   <input type = 'hidden' name = 'pass[{$key}]' value = '{$data[$key]['password']}'>
                   <input type = 'hidden' name = 'company[{$key}]' value = '{$data[$key]['comp_name']}'>";
   foreach ($val as $subkey => $value)
   {
             if (!(($subkey == 'username') OR ($subkey == 'password')))
            {
               $html .="<td>{$value}</td>";
            }
   }
   $html .="</tr>";
   }

   $html .="</table>
               <input type='submit' name='doSubmit' value = 'send'>
           </form>";
   echo $html;

   if (isset($_POST['doSubmit']))
   {
       include('send_mail_logins.php');
   }
   ```
2. send_mail_logins.php

   ```
   <?php
   require '/../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
   foreach ($_POST['name'] as $key=>$val)
   {   
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;     
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";             
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";  
        $mail->Port       = 587;           
        $mail->Username   = "camelia.petriu@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
        $mail->Password   = "password";            // GMAIL password

        $mail->From = 'camelia.petriu@gmail.com';
        $mail->FromName = 'camelia.petriu@com';
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;                               
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                 
        $mail->Subject = 'Request for Export Details';
        $mail->addAddress("{$_POST['email'][$key]}");

        $content ="<p>Dear {$val},</p>
               <p>...</p>
               Username: {$_POST['username'][$key]}
               Password: {$_POST['pass'][$key]}";
        $sent_to = "";
        $not_sent_to="";
        $mail->Body = $content;
        //$mail->AltBody = $altcontent;

        if(!$mail->send()) {
        $not_sent_to .= "<p style = 'color:red'>Message could not be sent to {$_POST['email'][$key]}.</p>";
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;}
        }
       else
       {
             $sent_to.= "<p>Message sent to {$_POST['email'][$key]}</p>";
       }
   }
   echo $sent_to;
   echo $not_sent_to;
   ```

I will later replace my gmail account with our organizational account

Many thanks!

Comment: are you receiving any error?

Comment: If you run that SQL query outside of your script, do you get the batch of 100 customers that you're after?

Comment: Yes, I get the whole list of customers in the first step. I replaced their email IDs with my own for testing. After I click 'send', I get no error but only receive like 23-25 messages.

Comment: I'd wager that this is because you're hitting GMail's send limits. See my answer below.

Comment: Another tip - no need to create a new PHPMailer instance every time around the loop - create one instance at the start and use it to send multiple messages, just changing the address it's sent to (call `clearAddresses` after sending each message) and the message body.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using GMail to send out batch emails, and I'd say you're having your error because you've hit the GMail sending limits. Be careful, because doing this too often could block your GMail account! (see http://www.labnol.org/internet/email/gmail-daily-limit-sending-bulk-email/2191/)

I'd recommend that you look into signing up to a proper transactional email service like [Mandrill](http://www.mandrill.com). Even their free tier allows you to send about 10,000 email per month.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That might be the case, though i got this problem already at my first trial, and i was not trying to send to more than 100, which seems to be the daily limit. But I will look into Mandrill.